# Canvas to high resolution image

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, dpi

I am working on web app which has to export a high definition image from canvas (which is kind of screen shot of the web page). So the exported image has to have up **300dpi** so it would be printable. 
Any known way of doing this ? 
What I have done some far is exporting the image with 96dpi which isnt quite what I was looking for ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just resize your canvas with css

```
var original_width = 1000;
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = original_width;
canvas.style.width = original_width / (300/96);
```